# Project Reactor: achieving mapping input Mono conditionally

Tags: project-reactor, reactive, declarative

I am trying to implement the following simple imperative logic:

```
boolean saveImperative(final List list) {
    final String existingList = readByNameImperative(list.getName());
    if (Objects.isNull(existingList)) {
        templateSaveImperative(existingList);
        return true;
    } else {
        templateSaveImperative(existingList);
        return false;
    }
}
```

using Project Reactor in declarative way and this is what I was able to achieve:

```
@Test
public void testDeclarative() {
    final Mono<List> list = createList("foo");
    final Boolean result = save(list).block();
    System.out.println(result);
}

private Mono<Boolean> save(final Mono<List> listMono) {
    final Mono<List> existingListMono = listMono.cache()
            .flatMap(list -> readByName(list.getName()));
    // if
    final Mono<List> savedListMono = existingListMono
            .flatMap(existingList -> templateSave(Mono.just(existingList)));
    final Mono<Boolean> trueResult = savedListMono.map(x -> true);

    // else
    return trueResult.switchIfEmpty(templateSave(existingListMono).map(x -> false));
}

private Mono<List> templateSave(final Mono<List> listMono) {
    return listMono.map(list -> {
        System.out.println("templateSave has been called");
        return list;
    });
}

private Mono<List> readByName(final String listName) {
    if (listName != "list001") {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    return createList(listName);
}

private Mono<List> createList(final String name) {
    final List list = List.builder().name(name).build();
    return Mono.just(list);
}

@Value
@Builder
private static class List {
    private final String name;
}
```

If I execute the test with `list001`, it will print:

```
templateSave has been called
true
```

as expected, but if I call it with `foo`, then I got

```
null
```

What I would be missing? I would expect an output like:

```
templateSave has been called
false
```

in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final Mono<List> existingListMono = listMono.cache()
    .flatMap(list -> readByName(list.getName()));
```

...in your save method, will take your existing list and flat map it using `readByName()`.

Your `readByName()` method is the following:

```
private Mono<List> readByName(final String listName) {
    if (listName != "list001") {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    return createList(listName);
}
```

(I don't believe it's related to this problem, but [don't use == or != for comparing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/string-equals-versus).)

Since your `listName` is `foo`, not `list001`, it returns an empty `Mono` - thus `existingListMono` becomes an empty Mono, and by implication so do `savedListMono` and `trueResult`.

When you call your `switchIfEmpty()` statement however, you pass in `templateSave(existingListMono)` - and since `existingListMono` is an empty `Mono` as above, the `save()` method returns an empty `Mono`.

...and when you block on an empty `Mono` you'll get null - hence the result.

As such, you may wish to use `listMono` instead of `existingListMono` in your return statement on the `save()` method, which will give you the result you're after:

```
trueResult.switchIfEmpty(templateSave(listMono).map(x -> false))
```